# Can't avformat_open_input an .mp3

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am trying to build a little C program using the ffmpeg library.
However I can't even open an audio file using `avformat_open_input()`
After setting up a function to check the error code I get the following output:

```
Error code: -1094995529
Invalid data found when processing input
```

And not

```
Error code: -2
No such file or directory
```

Which would be when I don't specify a correct file name.

After looking up about what this error code means, I made the assumption that my mp3 file must be missing informations in its header that `avformat_open_input()` needs to recognize its extension.

I have tried opening different mp3 files and even different formats. But I still get the same error.

Here is my main

```
const char *url = NULL;
AVFormatContext *s = NULL;
int ret = 0;
if (ac == 2)
    url = av[1];
else
    return (1);
ret = avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, NULL);
if (ret < 0) 
{
    check_error(ret);
    abort();
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `avformat_alloc_context()` first.

Also check [the example code](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decode__audio_8c_source.html) in the documentation.